# What is the vendor of identifierForVendor

Tags: ios, uuid, udid

I have some Apps whose **bundle IDs have same prefix**, such as, `com.mycompany.app1` and `com.mycompany.app2`, though their **Apple Developer accounts are different**.

When in development, I can get the same value by calling `identifierForVendor`. But it becomes different from each other when they are submitted on App Store.

The paragraph below described in [identifierForVendor section in Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice/1620059-identifierforvendor) confused me.

> Normally, the vendor is determined by data provided by the App Store. If the app was not installed from the app store (such as enterprise apps and apps still in development), then a vendor identifier is calculated based on the app’s bundle ID. The bundle ID is assumed to be in reverse-DNS format.

Apple doesn't tell us how the App Store determines the vendor, when Apps have been on the App Store.

Comment: `Vendor` is the owner of the the iTunes store account. All apps from the same developer have the same identifier.

Comment: @Sulthan That means the vendor is determined by the apps’ bundle ID when they are in development. And then it is determined by Developer account after they are submitted on App Store. Is it?

Comment: Basically that's it.

Comment: I am using the same developer account. But I get the IDs different when I install on a device. But on the simulator, i get the IDs same

Comment: @LohithKorupolu That is weird. Do you have some progress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have collected some schemes to identity a device.

## IDFV

Like written in the question, IDFV is the same for apps that come from the same vendor running on the same device.

Normally, the vendor is determined by data provided by the App Store. If the app was not installed from the app store (such as enterprise apps and apps still in development), then a vendor identifier is calculated based on the app’s bundle ID.

*Reference:* https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice/1620059-identifierforvendor?language=objc

## IDFA

Unlike IDFV, the same value is returned to all vendors. This identifier may change—for example, if the user erases the device. In iOS 10.0 and later, the value of advertisingIdentifier is all zeroes when the user has limited ad tracking.

An app may be rejected if the developer attempt to get IDFA without serving advertisements.

*Reference:* https://developer.apple.com/documentation/adsupport/asidentifiermanager/1614151-advertisingidentifier?language=objc

## Keychain Sharing

Same for apps that come from the same team ID.

*Reference:* https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services/keychain_items/sharing_access_to_keychain_items_among_a_collection_of_apps?language=objc

## DeviceCheck

Same for apps that come from the same Apple Developer account. Available from iOS 11.

*Reference:* https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicecheck?language=objc

## OpenUDID

Same for apps that come from the same team ID. This scheme is **deprecated**.

*Reference:* https://github.com/ylechelle/OpenUDID

## FCUUID

Same for apps that come from the same team ID.

*Reference:* https://github.com/fabiocaccamo/FCUUID